# Calling both the default and super constructor in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, super

I guess what I'd want is simply not possible, but I want to make sure. Say I have

```
public class bar {
    public bar() {

    }
    public bar(Object stuff) {
         // something done with stuff.
    }
}
```

and an extension

```
public class foobar extends bar {
    public foobar() {
        super();
        // some additional foobar logic here.    
    }
    public foobar(Object stuff) {
        // Do both the 
        // "some additional foobar logic" and 
        // "something done with stuff" here.
    }
}
```

How can I make the foobar(Object stuff) as simple as possible while also avoiding to duplicate code? I can't simply call super(stuff) as then "some additional foobar logic" isn't done, and I can't call just this() as then I don't do what I'd want to do with "stuff".

**NOTE :**
I realized I don't actually need to do this in this case, so this is now here only for theoretical purposes.

Comment: Call `super(stuff)` **and** *then* do "some additional foobar logic" stuff after that call.

Comment: You could do all the logic in `foobar(Object)` and check the parameter for null. Then call `this(null)` in `foobar()`.

Comment: It would really help if you'd be more specific (and use conventional names). Do you need to call the `bar(Object)` constructor from the `foobar(Object)` constructor?

Comment: In this case, I think you would have to live with duplicate code of the "some additional foobar logic"

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, that's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Thomas, true, that could be done, but that looks would look kinda of gnarly.

Comment: @JonSkeet Not sure what you mean by conventional names in this case. But yes, I do need to call the super. What I realized though is that I actually don't need to call the parameterless constructor (this()), so in this case I don't in fact have the problem described here. Nevertheless, I'm still curious about the question in general.

Comment: @Jeffed: I mean class names that follow the Java naming conventions - such as `FooBar` rather than `foobar`.

Comment: Oh right, true that, sorry.

Comment: If you create an initializer block, it will be copied into **every** constructor. That's the general way to avoid repetitious initialization.

Answer (score 5):

You can only chain to *one* constructor. Typically the best approach is for the "less specific" constructors (the ones with fewer parameters) to chain to the "more specific" ones, with a single "master" constructor which is the only one with logic in:

```
public class FooBar extends Bar {
    public FooBar() {
        this(null); // Or whatever value you want for "stuff"
    }

    public FooBar(Object stuff) {
        super(stuff);

        // Initialization logic
    }
}
```

Comment: But that would possibly incur a ```null``` check before using ```sutff```. Since there's no arguments to the common code, wouldn't it make more sense to just call an initializing method, or use an initializer block?

Comment: @JornVernee: It depends on the exact situation - but very commonly a parameterless constructor is *effectively* used to provide default values. Note that an initializing method can't write to `final` fields. An initializer block *might* make sense... it really depends on context, and the OP hasn't provided very much :(

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution. That doesn't however work if there is eg. two constructors FooBar(Object stuff) and FooBar(OtherObject otherObject) that both would need to do the same as FooBar(). An init block could be an option. But as I realized I don't in fact need to call both the basic parameterless constructor and the super, this is now theoretical in my case... or actually

Comment: @Jeffed: I don't know what you mean by that. There are two constructors here. Please be more precise with what you're trying to achieve. (It's very hard to give a precise solution to an imprecise question.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, sorry I was still editing. Accidentally posted the comment by pressing enter (thinking that would just result in a line change).

Comment: @Jeffed: My experience is that this is rarely a concern in well-designed objects - it's typical that you can just chain to a master constructor. Not 100% of the time, but sufficiently commonly that it's not worth speculating on exceptions to that, as they're all different.

Comment: Yep, agreed, that is most likely so! As it is, even in this case, the problem doesn't exist, I just didn't see it immediately, so I wanted to ask about this out of curiosity.

Comment: @JonSkeet It is now off the topic of the original post, but what I do have though as a problem of keeping things tidy is that I need to define multiple constructors that do nothing else but call their super equivalents with the same parameters. So having a FooBar(Object stuff) just to call super(stuff) and three other methods like that feels sort of silly.

Comment: @Jeffed: There are various other posts on that. Basically, there's no alternative to it, and good reasons why the language is designed that way... just live with it :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured there's no way around it, and yeah, I guess it can be sometimes good that it forces you to do that.

Comment: @JonSkeet When doing constructors that do nothing else besides call the super, it would be nice to be able to link the javadoc though. I've tried the annotations see and inheritDoc, but they don't seem to work.

Comment: @Jeffed: Yes, that much would be nice - although only if the superconstructor documentation is written in a way that lends itself to being used by the subclasses. If that says "Constructs a new instance of {superclass}" then it would look odd in the docs for the subclass. Would be nice to be able to inherit *bits* of the docs, such as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It may lead to cleaner code if you add an explicit `init()` function, that encapsulates the stuff you want to share between the constructors. Especially in your case, where you try to hop between constructors.

In the presented answer, the `super()` constructor is not executed. While `super()` is empty in your example, it is not neccessarily so in the future.

Also, you rely on `super(foo)` to handle `foo == null` properly. While it may be completely acceptable to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for the superclass, it is not for your use-case. You are basically extending the contract to initialize the superclass properly, using the parameterized constructor with a null parameter.

Using the `init`-method approach, code duplication is reduced and superclass has no extended contract. You may dislike the style, though. The constructor chaining avoids the additional method.

```
public class foobar extends bar {
    public foobar() {
        super();
        initFooBar(null);
    }

    public foobar(Object stuff) {
        super(stuff);
        initFooBar(stuff);
    }

    public void initFooBar(Object stuff) {
        // some additional foobar logic here.    
        // "something done with stuff" here.             
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the suggestion. I actually do have an init method there as well, which is called no matter what constructor is used, but it's just for a slightly different purpose. Still, having another one for doing initialization for the input parameters could also make sense.